# Foundation interchange image swap does not work correctly

Tags: zurb-foundation

The problem:

- When I resize the window the images will only sometimes change. It's almost like they get stuck / the resize event is not being captured properly by foundation. If I start resizing the window like a rabid monkey it will occasionally swap the image. If I resize the window according to the media queries and then refresh the page the correct image renders. This appears to be a resize only issue.

Other details:

- I have just a regular .html file (new site hosted from IIS on a separate machine) with a simple demo of Interchange image swapping.
- If I manually call: `$(document).foundation("interchange", "resize");` the image will swap correctly.
- Foundation version 5.3.1
- Testing in Chrome 36 and Firefox 31.
- So far the only built in media query that works is `(default)`. `(medium)`, `(large)` etc. do nothing, I have to write out the actually query to get it to work (or manually create them using named_queries. This may be an unrelated problem but does seem strange to me.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interchange</title>
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='/foundation.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/foundation.interchange.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/foundation.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/normalize.css' />

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            $(document).foundation();

            $(document).on('replace', function (e, newVal) {
                console.log(newVal);
            });

            // Adding this horrible hack will make it work 100% of the time.
            // BUT THIS SHOULD NOT BE NECESSARY!
            //$(window).resize(function(){
            //    $(document).foundation("interchange", "resize");
            //})
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <img data-interchange="[/images/space-small.jpg, (default)], [/images/space-medium.jpg, (only screen and (min-width: 641px))], [/images/space-large.jpg, (only screen and (min-width: 1000px))]">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL or jsFiddle replicating the issue? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/wonLaLwv/) using your provided code but perhaps its not the same.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Your version does seem to work. The problem is reproducible if you drop my code in and update the reference paths. [jsFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7uw4b6/). I was not using the "min" versions so I'm guessing there's something required that's not being included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question and it was indeed that odd `media queries` issue I described in the OP that lead me to the problem.

**Foundation's javascript is dependent on the Foundation CSS existing before it initializes.**

All I had to do was make sure the CSS link was above the script include and everything started working as expected.

Comment: Great, glad you got it figured out. Interesting to know too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help anyone, but I was getting the same issue but ONLY on Chrome. I added the foundation.min.css to my page like b1j suggested and voila! unfortunately though as I used the SASS version I couldn't just leave this included into the page as I would have double the amount of css included into my page. So I pasted the foundation.css contents into a style tag in the head of my document and deleted its contents bit by bit until I found the piece of css that fixed it. Here it is:

```
meta.foundation-mq-small {
    font-family: "/only screen/";
    width: 0em; }

meta.foundation-mq-medium {
    font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:40.063em)/";
    width: 40.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-large {
    font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
    width: 64.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-xlarge {
    font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:90.063em)/";
    width: 90.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-xxlarge {
    font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:120.063em)/";
    width: 120.063em; }
```

Not sure why this wasn't compiled into my CSS but I will look, but incase anyone needs a quick fix, this should do it!

Comment: Sorry, I could have saved you a ton of time as I came to the same conclusion but didn't post the snippet in my answer. Keep in mind there may be other functionality that breaks due to other missing CSS even though the only thing we've come across so far is interchange.